# Meta refresh tag not working in (my) firefox?

Tags: firefox, redirection, metadata

Code like on [this page](http://www.fluffbucket.com/howto/example1.htm) does not work in (my) Firefox 3.6 and also not in Fx4b11 (WinXPsp3)
Works in IE8, Safari 5, Opera 11, Mozilla 1.7, Chrome 9

`<meta http-equiv=refresh content="12; URL=meta2.htm">`

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=http://fully_qualified_url.com/page2.html">`

are completely ignored

Not that I use such back-button killing things, but a LOT of sites do, possibly including my linux apache it seems when it wants to show a 503 error page...

If I firebug or look at generated content, I do not see the refresh tag changed in any way so I am really curious what kind of plugin/addon could block me which is why I googled (in vain) for a known bug...

In about:config I have `accessibility.blockautorefresh; false` so that is not it.
I ran in **safe mode** and ***OH MY GOD, STACKEXCHANGE IS FULL OF ADS*** but no redirect

UPDATE: Firefox 5 does not show this behaviour and redirects as expected

Comment: offtopic, belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not at all. It is a problem with *firefox* not a server!!!

Comment: Do you have any add-ons that might affect it?

Comment: What is the behavior of other browsers? Can you try accessing a different site using this refresh method in Firefox to see if it works there?

Comment: All other browsers I have works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has gone away for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `about:config` (enter `about:config` as url), there is setting `accessibility.blockautorefresh`, set it as false.

Comment: Was false, but +1 for a good place to sstart

Answer (score 1):

See if the problem exists with Mozilla Firefox (Safe Mode).

If the problem doesn't occur any more, then it is caused by an extension. Disable in this case the extensions until you locate the guilty one.

Comment: Maybe you could try uninstalling Firefox, deleting all directories and full reinstall.

Comment: Just installed Fx 4 from scratch. Same behaviour

Comment: Fx 5 works - not sure who's answer to accept

Comment: Was any extension(s) disabled by moving to FF5 ? If yes, then this may be the problematic extension and my above answer may apply. If not, then this was a bug in FF4 that was fixed in FF5 (there were about 1000 bugs fixed in FF5!).

Comment: Likely a bug since safe mode didn't help